# java - Hibernate : listing of mapped class with heirs returns the content of both parent class and its heirs

Tags: hibernate, jpa, inheritance, criteria

I have two tables with the same column set:

```
CREATE t1
(
  id INTEGER NOT NULL
);

CREATE t2
(
  id INTEGER NOT NULL
);
```

They are mapped to classes c1 and c2 which extends c1:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t1")
public class c1
{
    @Id
    @Column
    protected Integer id;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "t2")
public class c2 extends c1
{
}
```

When i do

```
Criteria criteria = this.getSession().createCriteria(c1.class).list();
```

it selects both from tables t1 and t2, so i get the rows from two tables, not only the t1 as desired. If i remove the inheritance from c2 class the problem goes away, but i'd like to keep it. How can i make list return data only from t1 table?

Answer (score 0):

One of the options would be the creation of an abstract MappedSuperclass that would hold the common values but would not be considered as an entity:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    protected Integer id;
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "t1")
public class c1 extends BaseEntity
{

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "t2")
public class c2 extends BaseEntity
{
}
```

If you need you can further override the columns if needed:

```
@AttributeOverride(name="id", column=@Column(name="t2_id"))
@Entity
@Table(name = "t2")
public class c2 extends BaseEntity
{
}
```

Comment: The problem is that c1 is from hereditary code which i'd like to avoid changing.